# PHP rewrite giving 404, .htaccess problem?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /phptest
```

on my local testing server (http://localhost) I have to uncomment the first line for the site to work. Otherwise I get Error 403 (Forbidden).

Once I upload the page to my webserver (FastHosts) I get Error 500 (Internal Server Error) if the first line is not commented out.

If I comment it out, my page loads but it cannot find the page content which is mydomain.com/phptest/Home

I get a 404.

Any suggestions on what the problem might be?

Comment: It looks like you have a different configuration on your server than you do with `localhost`.

Comment: It appears so, how can I check? I have nothing but ftp access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Check for [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html) to be disabled. It gives unexpected results in combination with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your httpd.conf to allow for AllowOverride All

What does your error log say?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether mod_rewrite is enable or not in your php.ini file. If not then please enable that.

Comment: would t show up in phpinfo? I don't have access to the servers configuration files.

Comment: Yes, it would show in the output of phpinfo() ... search for mod_rewrite